# Eclipse Compiling for Debug vs Native Debug (C++ Code)

Tags: c++, eclipse, build, compiler-errors

I am having an issue compiling in Eclipse Mars.1.  I have a C++ program that I've been working on and have it working to the point that I want to put it somewhere other than on my machine.  I'm not that great with Eclipse so bear with me...I have everything compiled and working when my Build Configuration is set to "Native Debug", but when I change it to "Debug", the program doesn't build.  I get an error code....

Make: Error 127.

I'm hoping this is just a setting that needs to be changed, but I can't find the answer.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Check the build configuration settings of "Native Debug" build config.

Right click on your C++ project. Select `Properties` option then check the settings of both build configurations.

You can easily find out the difference between these two build configurations and spot the cause of this error.

[image]

Comment: Thanks..I actually found out that my PATH wasn't correct.  I'm using an earlier branch from a repository project that had another filepath listed.  I didn't notice it right away because it worked in "Native Debug" so I figured it should work in "Debug" and "Release" as well.  Come to find out, "Native Debug" uses a local compiler, and so the issue arises when I need the cross compiler.  Long story short...Check your "Tool Settings"!